# Type of a prop based on type of other props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a general component that accepts a prop named `component` and the rest of the props should be the props of that specific component. how can I do it in typescript?

i.e. :

```
 <FormField component={Input} ... />
```

This FormField should accept whatever props `Input` component accepts.

Note:

- I want to infer the type from props. don't want to pass additional type

Comment: `<FormField component={<Input {...props} />} ... />` you sure you can't do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this using a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)

```
const FormField = <K,>(props: FormFieldProps & K) => {
    //Your component here
}
```

Usage :

```
<FormField<InputProps> .... />
```

Comment: `K` has to be the Input props Type, not the Input component itself, am i wrong? Something like `<FormField<InputProps> .... />`

Answer (score 0):

Starting from @A.Vinuela's answer, i just make it more easy to use, without the need to know the component's props interface, using also the React build-in helpers.

---

I think you can do this using a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) and the `React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<T>` build-in helper (or the `React.ComponentPropsWithRef<T>`, depending on your needs).

```
const FormField = <K>(props: FormFieldProps & React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<K>) => {
    //Your component here
}
```

Usage :

```
<FormField<typeof AnyComponent> .... />
```

---

Unfortunately it is not possible to determine the type of a property depending on the dynamic type of another property (*at least, that I know of*).

What you ***would*** need is:

```
// UNFORTUNATELY THIS IS NOT VALID
interface FormFieldProps {
component: T,
props: React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<T>
}
```

But you can't use a dynamic type variable such as `T` as the type of the `component` prop.

So i think that the best solution is using the generic as shown above.